# Lie algebra (co)homology of the Lie algebra of differential operators

Tags: homological-algebra, lie-algebras, differential-operators, lie-algebra-cohomology, cyclic-homology

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety (or a complex manifold) over $\mathbb C$. Let $D(X)$ be its algebra of differential operators. Mostly I am interested in algebraic differential operators, but the case of smooth coefficients is also interesting(though the computation of Hochschild/cyclic (co)homology for these options coincide).

What is known about cohomology of $D(X)$ of this algebra viewed as a Lie algebra?

I know how to compute cyclic and Hohschild (co)homology of $D(X)$ and there is a theorem of Loday and Quillen which relates Lie algebra homology of $\mathfrak{gl}_{\infty}(A)$ to cyclic homology of $A$ for any algebra $A$, but Lie algebra homology of $A$ and $\mathfrak{gl}_{\infty}(A)$ may differ greately as some cycles may die on the infinite level.

Comment: Could you say what is $A$? And how do you define differential operator: with polynomial/analytic/smooth/continuous coefficients?

Comment: (+ fix the typo "Lle algebra", "HoChschild" and missing space before "(or complex manifold)" , then I'll erase this comment)

Comment: ... and no idea what you mean by "homology of $A$"

Comment: @YCor Thank you for you comments, tried to make the question clearer

Comment: you left "Hohschild", it's "Hochschild", and you now say "the Lie algebra homology of $A$" which I don't understand ($A$ is meant to be an associative algebra)

Answer (score 1):

Lie algebra (co)homology of the Lie algebra of differential operators
was used in the Feigin-Tsygan works on the Riemann-Roch theorem.
See, for example, [this paper](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/701432/WSGP_08-1988-1_4.pdf) and later papers of Tsygan with co-authors.